# How can I automate GIF to PNG with Preview using AppleScript?

Tags: applescript, preview

I have a GIF file but I can open it only with Preview because it is a little bit ruined (GIMP or other programs does not open it correctly but it works with Preview).

I want to export it to PNG files. As far as I know the only way to do it is:

1. Manually select the next frame
2. File → Export
3. Choose the right format to export and specify the path
4. Click Save and repeat

I'd like to automate it. Some advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to use something like [php](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/111179/10733), or a [workflow](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/111059/10733).

There are no AppleScript dictionaries for [Preview](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/111016/10733).  Which means you would not be able to do it in AppleScript.

Comment: "There are no AppleScript dictionaries for Preview." this is the answer!

Comment: Preview has actually had a basic AppleScript dictionary by default since 10.9, but there is no "Preview suite" or no commands for manipulating images.

Answer (score 2):

You could also try using ImageMagick:

```
convert -coalesce animation.gif frame%04d.png
```

You can install ImageMagick with `brew install imagemagick` or `sudo port install imagemagick`.

Comment: Although this doesn't involve Preview as per the OP's question, this will solve your problem. .

Comment: Probably this automation can be done in GraphicConverter as well.  But still, that is not Preview as required.